# Summing data for individuals over a series of rounds in R

Tags: r, sum

I am currently working on my masters thesis and part of my data analysis is in R. I am completely new to it and so am learning as I go along.

The experiments we are running consist of individuals playing a token allocation game, over a series of rounds.

I need to change the current csv file in R so that each individual appears in one row, with ingroup, outgroup and self giving summed over the 40 rounds they played.

Currently, the data frame  is as follows:

```
id       roundno        tokenstoingroup    tokenstooutgroup     tokenstoself
0001        1                 1                   0                  0
0001        2                 0                   1                  0
0002        1                 0                   0                  1
```

etc...

There are many participants (over a thousand), and every round's allocation for each participant is entered.

My question is:

How do I sum this up so that the data frame looks more like this??

```
id      totalrounds  tokenstoingroup      tokenstooutgroup   tokenstoself
0001       40             25                13                     2

002        40             13                13                     14
```

etc...

As I have said, I am totally new to this. I have tried to look online for aggregating and summing things up, but I have idea where to start with something a bit more complex like this.

Comment: Try `library(dplyr); df1 %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise_each(funs(sum))`

Comment: It tells me: Error: invalid 'type' (character) of argument

Comment: Then, you may need to check the `str(df1)`.  If the columns are character or factor, convert to numeric.

Comment: There are some columns in between those i mentioned that consist of categorical variables (the conditions we manipulated in the experiments.

Comment: In that case, you can specify the columns to get the sum in the `summarise_each` i.e. `summarise_each(funs(sum), roundno, tokenstoingroup)` etc.

Comment: so there is 'id    equalitycondition    normcondition    groupness    tokensto ingroup' etc

Comment: I see! I will try that. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Thanks @akrun that worked perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `summarise_each` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(sum), roundno, tokenstoingroup,tokenstooutgroup,   tokenstoself)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `aggregate` function with `cbind`. As an example, let's create a data frame:

```
test <- data.frame('id'=rep(c('A','B','C'),each=2),'C1'=rep(1,6),'C2'=1:6)
> test
     id C1 C2
   1  A  1  1
   2  A  1  2
   3  B  1  3
   4  B  1  4
   5  C  1  5
   6  C  1  6
```

Then:

```
test <- aggregate(cbind(C1,C2)~id,data=test,sum)
> test
   id C1 C2
1  A  2  3
2  B  2  7
3  C  2 11
```